# Programming a function in Maple

Tags: function, parameters, maple

What is the equivalent to a procedural C function in Maple? Maple tells me that a module cannot except parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Maple module can be applied to arguments and thus act as a function call if it has an exported member named `ModuleApply`.

In that case a function call (involving module `m`) of the form `m(...arguments...)` will invoke the call `m:-ModuleApply(...arguments...)`.

See [ModuleApply](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ModuleApply)